# gcc options to detect "forward references to ‘enum’ types"

Tags: c, gcc, enums

When compile the following code using gcc with `-Werror=pedantic`, it will report `error: ISO C forbids forward references to 'enum' types [-Werror=pedantic]`.

```
enum foo foo_test(void);

enum foo {
    FOO_0
};

enum bar {
    BAR_0
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("sizeof(enum foo) %zu, sizeof(enum bar) %zu\n",
           sizeof(enum foo), sizeof(enum bar));
    return 0;
}
```

In my project, I am using many third party open source code, and some source code has the same problem of the above. If I add `-Werror=pedantic` to gcc options, it will cause many errors. I want to detect error about *forward references to 'enum' types* only, but no extra errors. Is there another gcc option can report this error?

gcc version: arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.9.3

Comment: Tested your code on https://godbolt.org. It doesn't compile even without `-Werror=pedantic`

Comment: @xvan umm, wrong link perhaps? Notice that the compiler must be GCC for this to compile, it is using a GCC extension

Comment: @xvan seriously? I couldn't find a compiler on which this *wasn't* compiling?

Comment: The correct approach is to always compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` and then make sure it compiles cleanly. Particularly important for an ARM environment! Since portability to other compilers for the same core is likely. (You'll likely want `-ffreestanding` for ARM, too) If you have some open source crap that fails to compile under standard C, get rid of it. Note that open source more often than not tends to fall under the category "you get what you pay for".

Comment: @Lundin "open source cr*p that fails to compile under standard C" includes ... umm Linux, among others.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Indeed. Linux is probably one of the most poorly-written code bases I have ever seen. I used to like Linux until I got the idea to peek underneath the hood. Now I keep a 10 meter safety distance to all Linux computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-pedantic` without any `-Werror`. It will produce just a warning but doesn't stop the compilation. You can gather all these diagnostics into a log file and then analyse them by `grep`ping. For example

```
% make 2> errors.log
% grep -A 3 "ISO C forbids forward references to 'enum' types" errors.log
```